# JQuery como setar um valor em um campo com mask de CPF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, css3

**Tenho um input usando uma mascara de CPF exemplo :**

```
$("#cpfDependente").mask('000.000.000-00');
```

**e estou tentando setar um valor no input desse jeito**

```
$("#cpfDependente").val(dependente.cpf);
```

**Ele seta corretamente o problema é que a mascara some qual a solução disso? desde já agradeço !**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que encontrei foi de adicionar a propriedade `data-mask="000.000.000-00"` de mascara no próprio HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" id="cpfDependente" name="cpfDependente" type="text" data-mask="000.000.000-00"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Inverta a ordem.

Adicione este comando:

```
$("#cpfDependente").val(dependente.cpf);
```

em seguinda adicione a mascara:

```
$("#cpfDependente").mask('000.000.000-00');
```

Comment: Só para completar, olha um [exemplo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/my0oag9n/4/). +1 pela resposta.

Comment: Já tinha tentado isso mas não foi !

Comment: Você deve adicionar a mascara no $( document ).ready(function() {
   //Aqui a mascara
});